# Range queries on 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, query-optimization

I have very huge table Shelve(approximately 100 millions) which has Shelve info for books.

Shelve

```
ShevleID     RangeStart      RangeEnd  
----------------------------------------
   1               1           100
   2             200           500
   3             501           1000
```

Each book has unique number BookID given to it. Lets say you have a book with BookID 50.
Then Book must be kept in Shelve 1 because 50 lies between 1 and 100.

Books

```
BookID     BookName
---------------------------
   1       Book1
   2       Book2
   .
   .
  50       Book3
```

My queries are like this-

```
SELECT 
    BookID, 
    BookName, 
    ShelveID
FROM 
    Book B
LEFT JOIN  
    Shelve S 
      ON B.BookID 
                BETWEEN 
                       S.RenageStart 
                       AND
                       S.RangeEND
```

This query is super slow because query is able to use index only one of the columns either RangeStart or RangeEnd at a time.

I have already tried these 5 options-

1. Create Index on StartIP
2. Create Index on EndIP
3. Create included Index on StartIP (included column EndIP)
4. Create included Index on EndIP (included column StartIP)
5. Create Index on StartIP,EndIP

Can someone please suggest me some approach to achieve this?

Comment: Does your query return one row or many rows?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, ***please*** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Why not store the assigned ShelveID in the book table?  That is where the attribute belongs since you have a zero or one relationship between Book and Shelve.  The non-normalized design is the root cause of the performance issue as joining one inequality operators are problematic from a performance perspective.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff  This queries retruns more than 1 rows. One row for each book.

Comment: @Dan - We have to change location of book every 3 days or so and Shelve table is populated by by secret code.shelve table is regularly changing so we cannot store shelveID in Book table. We can just optimize the read part.

Comment: You said there are 100 million shelves. How many books are there? What happens if you remove "LEFT" from JOIN?

Comment: Is this really about IP ranges? There are solutions for that on Stack Overflow already.

Comment: is it possible that  a book has no shelve?

Comment: Yes, it is possible that a book has no shelve

Answer (score 2):

If you want one shelve value for each book, you can try:

```
SELECT b.*,
       (SELECT TOP 1 s.ShelveId
        FROM Shelve S
        WHERE b.BookId >= s.RangeStart
        ORDER BY s.RangeStart DESC
       ) as ShelveId
FROM Book B;
```

This should make effective use of an index on `Shelve(RangeStart, ShelveId)`.

This assumes that you want one `ShelveId` and the book ranges are not overlapping.

I am curious what your real application is.  No libraries (to the best of my knowledge) have hundreds of millions of books.

EDIT:

You can handle the missing `ShelveId` with a `case` statement:

```
SELECT b.*,
       (SELECT TOP 1 (case when b.BookId between s.RangeStart and s.RangeEnd then s.ShelveId end)
        FROM Shelve S
        WHERE b.BookId >= s.RangeStart
        ORDER BY s.RangeStart DESC
       ) as ShelveId
FROM Book B;
```

If the other assumptions are true, this may solve your problem.

EDIT II:

If you want other attributes, then try `cross apply`.  It should have similar performance characteristics:

```
SELECT b.*,
       s.*
FROM Book B CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT TOP 1 (case when b.BookId between s.RangeStart and s.RangeEnd then s.ShelveId end) as RangeStart, . . .
        FROM Shelve S
        WHERE b.BookId >= s.RangeStart
        ORDER BY s.RangeStart DESC
       ) s
```

Now, comes a bit of experimentation.  I would like to write:

```
SELECT b.*,
       s.*
FROM Book B CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT TOP 1 s.*
        FROM Shelve S
        WHERE b.BookId >= s.RangeStart and b.BookId <= s.RangeEnd
        ORDER BY s.RangeStart DESC
       ) s
```

But, this might confuse the optimization engine and prevent the use of the index.  If it works, great.  If it doesn't work, I would suggest either using the first version with a `case` for every variable.  Or, use the correlated subquery version and join back to the `Shelve` table on a primary key.

Comment: Yes book ranges are not overlapping. This is real application for online book store.

Comment: There is one problem here. The bookID may not exist between any of the given ranges. In that case i have to return null. In given situation for bookID 150 shevleID should be NULL.

Comment: Thanks a lot.This approach is showing good performance improvement. Just a small ask. I need to get few other attributes apart from ShelveID from shelve table. Is joining this result with Shelve Table is the only way to get that or there is some better way?  I want (Book.* , ShelveID,ShelveName,ShelveServerID........) columns in the result

Comment: Case statement is still omiting the bookIDs which do not lie withing any range

Comment: My bad - Actually Changing "ORDER BY s.RangeStart" to "ORDER BY s.RangeStart DESC" helped.

Comment: @JitendraRathor . . . I feel very awkward about having gotten that backwards.  I'm glad you found it; it suggests that you understand how the query is working.

Comment: @GordanLinoff Thanks a lot for suggesting this. I know internals of this and i understood how it works. This approach just didn't strike my mind