# Find all the ranges overlapping with given range

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, query-optimization

I have a table called Range. Which has ranges start and end. I want to know what are the ranges in Range table which are overlapping with given range.

```
For Ex - 
Range Table
RId Start End
1     1    2
2     3    5
3     10   20
4     6    8

Given range : 2-8
```

Then I should return Rids of overlapping ranges i.e. 1,2,4.

I have a solution for this which works. But i am looking for performance optimization.

```
Range Table size = 680 million rows
Start and End are BIGINT type.

This is an extension of 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27580384/range-queries-on-2-columns

Here result may be more 1 rows
```

Edited -

```
Here is my current solution - 

CREATE TABLE #Range
(
RID int,
StartR BIGINT,
EndR BIGINT)

INSERT INTO #Range
SELECT 1,     1 ,   2 UNION ALL
SELECT 2,     3,    5  UNION ALL
SELECT 3,     10,   20  UNION ALL
SELECT 4,     6,    8

DECLARE @s BIGINT = 2, @e BIGINT = 8


SELECT 
    RId
FROM #Range
WHERE
    @e >= StartR
    AND EndR >= @s
```

I have created 2 separate indices on Start and End and one on Start and End .

Comment: Kindly post your working solution.

Comment: It would be best if you gave us the code you are using - otherwise how do we know if it is/isn't optimal already? Also you refer to another question on SE, but that included two tables. Do you only care about optimizing this part?

Comment: Why -1 for the question?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the ff query to get the overlapping ranges.

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM #Range
WHERE
    @e >= StartR
    AND EndR >= @s
```

You should probably add an index on `(StartR, EndR)`.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX NCIX_Range ON #Range(StartR,EndR)
```

Comment: It performs same as solution one.

Comment: @JitendraRathor but your solutions will not cover all posibilities